# Can't handle events in ASP.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am new to ASP.net. I downloaded one responsive page template from this [link](https://onepagelove.com/tempo). For my convenience I changed this HTML code to asp.net web form(i.e .html to .aspx) I added a button in that page and I generated click event. When I place a breakpoint in the .cs code and when I click this button in the browser the event is not handled. Even I tried with link button and other controls. I wrote some code in page_load event. It works perfectly. How to solve this issue. Any problem with the downloaded template or can't I handle events in such type of layout. Please go through the below code

[image]

Even I tried placing outside the html list control. Its not working. Please go through the link for the details of template [here](https://onepagelove.com/tempo)

**Issue** Placed Menu but event is not working. I tried using other control and its working..

```
 <asp:Menu ID="mini" OnMenuItemClick="mini_MenuItemClick" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Items> <asp:MenuItem Text="Item">
              <asp:MenuItem Text="sdaad" Value="1">
                  <asp:MenuItem Text="MenuSub1" Value="MenuSub1" ></asp:MenuItem>
                  <asp:MenuItem Text="MenuSub2" Value="MenuSub2" ></asp:MenuItem>
              </asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Item" Value="Item">
                  <asp:MenuItem Text="MenuSub" Value="MenuSub"></asp:MenuItem>
              </asp:MenuItem>
              </asp:MenuItem></Items>
      </asp:Menu>
```

Comment: Just delete that button and write a new code line for a button and create a new event.

Comment: show your full design code and code behind. Your phrase "I changed .html to .aspx" sounds strange.

Comment: Need to see your page directive .. how it is , is it linked with the .cs where you wrote the clickevent

Comment: I already tried what you said but it is not working @MattMurdock

Comment: `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>`   this is my page directive @Webruster

Comment: post ur .cs partial class name !!

Comment: `public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page`

Comment: please go through the link for the project sample [here] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WbYVJblzMoWjhSZTlLRlR6MEU/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried again after download that template and get issue if because of jQuery Validation script, there are three text boxes in bottom so when we are click on our asp.net button then page will first run client side script and client side script will return false so it will not do post-back till validation js will not return true, so to solve asp.net click problem just remove :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
```

Comment: would you please provide me Default.aspx.cs page code also

Comment: Got issue there are three text boxes in bottom and on them jquery validation script if firing that's whay the problem is coming so please remove the jquery validation references : " <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script> " and check will work.

Comment: Hi, please read above answer i have just changed and now it will work.

Comment: Now I removed that Bootstrap validation but when I click the button it show s error(server error in / application)  `Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.`

Comment: there is a page directive on top like this : <%@ Page Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="true" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="Tempo_Design_Test.Index" %>                       you change --- EnableEventValidation="false" in it. then then try

Comment: Hi Vaibhav, Today I tried placing ASP:Menu control and generated event it is not working. When I placed a button it worked fine.. Please help me. I updated my question

Comment: which type of action do you want by using menubar.

Comment: I added menu control to design. Edited menu items with its sub items. I have a grid view with the data bound to the database. When I select the sub menu item the gridview with the data should be shown below the menu. So by generating event I though it can be handled but when I select sub menu item the event is not fired

Comment: I also checked the total template but I cant find the issue for this menu items

Comment: will you please send me your template page (.aspx, .aspx.cs) on vchaurasiya4@gmail.com

Comment: Ok i will check it. and let you know the problem

Comment: Hi, i have got the issue.

Comment: actually there are more than one form that is : '  <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm"> .... <form>  '  remove that there are no use of that when we have already put form on top. and please confirm me. working on my end. do you use skype ?

Comment: because of that <form> asp.net view-states are not getting properly initialized.

Comment: Actually my main issue is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217130/bind-naviagte-menu-items-in-web-forms-asp-net but because of this event handling I blocked here. Please solve this issue

Comment: so what code you written on -->> mini_MenuItemClick, i hope this will work.

Comment: But when I click on main menu item it starts executing but actually I want to select sub menu item..

Comment: but it will also do post back when user click on main menu also i think we can do this modification in asp.net menubar. but i hope there are some changes to do this by using javascript to avoid postback on mainmenu click.

Comment: How to handle this issue I am not aware of javascript

Comment: It's is time taking, need to do much r&d fro that.

Comment: Hi vaibhav will you please recheck my project. I cant handle gridview event. Only hope on you. Please go through this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WbYVJblzModXJfRGNrNmphdWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also please check it and help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416972/popup-not-raised-in-a-linkbutton-click-of-gridview/34417180#34417180

Answer (score 0):

Have you attached ID to your button? Give ID to your Button and try again. As it is server control, it is not so logical to use it without ID... And post your code behind, I need to look at it and then may be I could help you.

Comment: Yes I done it. I think the problem is with the template. Once check the template code whether the event fires in that template. Check the sample and please solve it https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WbYVJblzMoWjhSZTlLRlR6MEU/view

Answer (score 0):

One way to check whether the event has been bound to the control, is to go to the design view of the page, select properties for the button, see the section for events and check whether an event has been attached to click. If not double click in the click event section and an event will get attached to your element.

[Button.Click event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click(v=vs.110).aspx)

Why do you want to put that button inside a list control?

Comment: Yes I done it. But everything is fine in the code. I think the problem is other than this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WbYVJblzMoWjhSZTlLRlR6MEU/view

Answer (score 0):

- Give an ID to your button control.

  ```
   ID="Button1"
  ```
- Your Click event should be like this:

  ```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  //some code
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Find and change Categories block to the next:

```
<div class="categories">
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
  <ul class="cat">
    <li>
      <ol class="type">

        <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="active">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".web">Web Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".app">App Development</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".branding">Branding</a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>

</div>
```

your ButtonClickListenes is:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Button is working');</script>");
}
```

Your code behind (full version):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        MyFunction();
}

protected void MyFunction()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-CEUQVES;Initial Catalog=register;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Admintr where projectid=mba ", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        //GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    }
}

protected void Unnamed_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "view")
    {
        string str = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

        Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + str + "\"");
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(str));
        Response.End();
    }
}




protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Button is working');</script>");
}
```