# Popup not raised in a linkbutton click of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, modalpopupextender

I am trying to show a popup from a grid view. But when I try to run the below code in the website the popup panel is not visible. But when I remove the style for panel(i.e display=none;) then it just shows like a panel and not like a popup. In a button click of the link button in the grid view I am trying to show a popup. Help me...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:GridView ID="minidata" CssClass="table" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="abstract">

                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="pid" HeaderText="MyFileId" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="video" HeaderText="MyFileurl" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="abstract">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="lnkDownload_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>

                            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>


                            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panel1" Height="200px" Width="300px" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" style="display:none;">
                                <div>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="sacca"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="emails" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server">5e76d</asp:LinkButton>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>

                            </asp:Panel>
                            <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" PopupControlID="panel1" TargetControlID="Button1" runat="server"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" Style="display: none;" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="minidata" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the .cs file

```
    LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
    GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    string filePath = minidata.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    HiddenField1.Value = filePath;
    emails.Text = "myemail";
    this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
```

[image]

And when I inspect the website I cannot found the panel displayed in the page

[image]

Comment: onclick must write in lowercase

Comment: yes but I got same errors

Comment: Will you please check my project via team viewer. I am fed up with this.. Please help me

Comment: Ok give codes to access or view your app

Comment: my id : 581 133 073, and password is 9359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah I knew that before. You have to simulate the click on the TargetControl of your modalPopupExtender. So in your code it seems to be Button1.

So try to do that by replacing this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="lnkDownload_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

with

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" onclick="$('[id$=Button1]').click()"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Your server-side code is not useful for this method

### EDIT

Ok, you just haven't JQuery in your app ^^.

Could you add JQuery in your app or it is a constraint ?

If it is, waiting I found you a native JavScript code, try by including this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"/>
```

Comment: I got the above errors when I copy your code. Updated my question

Comment: Any solution for the issue